# Перезапуска сервиса не происходит на смартфонах xiaomi

Tags: service, android-service, уведомления

Есть приложение, в нем есть нотификации, при запущенном приложении нотификации отображаются, за это отвечает сервис, когда закрываем АПП и убираем его из "recents" - умирает и сервис, но в сервисе, в onTaskRemoved я посылаю broadcast, ресивер перезапускает сервис. Но смартфоны xiaomi минуют onTaskRemoved, что-то связанно с батареей. На motorola moto m всё происходит как надо. На xiaomi - нет. Что делать?

Comment: Сделать сервис который не закрывается при закрытии активности. он требует иконку и постоянную нотификацию в уведомлениях, что он работает.

Comment: Есть ссылка, где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/165-urok-100-service-intentservice-foreground-avtozagruzka-servisa.html

Comment: спасибо, проблема решена